# How to make stream data PHP+Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, streaming

i'm trying to create a data Streaming like Facebook, 
when scroll down a New data **uploaded**!  using PHP and jquery

Comment: exactly loading more content :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean loading more content? That's called 'infinite scrolling'

one of many jQuery plugins: http://jscroll.com